# connect c# socket client with php socket server

Tags: c#, php, sockets

I have created a C# socket  server and client program. It is working fine in the local network. Then I have created a PHP socket server and run it on my lacal xampp server. I tried connecting this php server and C# client and it works perfectly.

What I want to know how to connect C# socket client that is running on  the local PC to PHP socket server that is running on remote web server? I tried by it gives me this Error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   138.xxx.xxx.xx:1233

138.xxx.xxx.xx is my domain IP address. And port 1233. I don't use any web services here.

What is the proper way to do this?

Plaease help. (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: is it being blocked by a firewall? Usually that is the case.

Comment: Try this command from your client before `telnet 138.xxx.xxx.xx 1233`

Comment: where do I have to use telnet  command? @Halayem Anis

Comment: shell//command prompt :)